# Get terminal size in Go

Tags: go, tty

How to get tty size with Golang? I am trying do this with executing `stty size` command, but I can't craft code right.

```
package main

import (
  "os/exec"
  "fmt"
  "log"
)

func main() {
  out, err := exec.Command("stty", "size").Output()
  fmt.Printf("out: %#v\n", out)
  fmt.Printf("err: %#v\n", err)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
out: []byte{}
err: &exec.ExitError{ProcessState:(*os.ProcessState)(0xc200066520)}
2013/05/16 02:35:57 exit status 1
exit status 1
```

I think this is because Go spawns a process not related to the current tty, with which it is working. How can I relate the command to current terminal in order to get its size?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It works if you give the child process access to the parent's `stdin`:

```
package main

import (
  "os/exec"
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  cmd := exec.Command("stty", "size")
  cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
  out, err := cmd.Output()
  fmt.Printf("out: %#v\n", string(out))
  fmt.Printf("err: %#v\n", err)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
out: "36 118\n"
err: <nil>
```

Comment: You can try to put these lines into a function, and set a unit test by `testing` module to test the function, you will find that you always get empty array.

Comment: I have tried it but I keep getting an empty array as @Kingname stated when testing.

Comment: @Kingname Is that not because go test turns into a separate process with a separate stdin ?

Answer (score 38):

I just wanted to add a new answer since I ran into this problem recently. There is a terminal package which lives inside the official ssh package https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal.

This package provides a method to easily get the size of a terminal.

`width, height, err := terminal.GetSize(0)`

0 would be the file descriptor of the terminal you want the size of. To get the fd or you current terminal you can always do `int(os.Stdin.Fd())`

Under the covers it uses a syscall to get the terminal size for the given fd.

Comment: If `os.Stdin` is not attached to the terminal, like when reading from a pipe, you can use `int(os.Stdout.Fd())` to find the dimensions instead.

Comment: It didn't worked for me on Windows, unfortunately. No matter what I do it sends me error `The handle is invalid.`

Comment: To me, ```int(os.Stdin.Fd())``` not working but ```int(os.Stdout.Fd())``` working properly. -  Working on WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04, VSCode, with command ```$ go test -run TestTerminalSize```

Answer (score 28):

I was stuck on a similar problem. Here is what I ended up with.

It doesn't use a subprocess, so might be desirable in some situations.

```
import (
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

type winsize struct {
    Row    uint16
    Col    uint16
    Xpixel uint16
    Ypixel uint16
}

func getWidth() uint {
    ws := &winsize{}
    retCode, _, errno := syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_IOCTL,
        uintptr(syscall.Stdin),
        uintptr(syscall.TIOCGWINSZ),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(ws)))

    if int(retCode) == -1 {
        panic(errno)
    }
    return uint(ws.Col)
}
```

Comment: Another alternative without using "unsafe" package: https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/e4dc69e5b2fd71dcaf8bd5d054eb936deb78d1fa/ssh/terminal/util.go#L80

Comment: Unfortunately that alternative still ends up using unsafe under the hood. https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/572b51eaf7221935bdec454796989ba8318fa6f3/unix/syscall_linux.go#L112

Comment: @Strom: the way I see it, it's a safe wrapper around an unsafe function. Kinda like with Rust :)

Comment: This works for me, I was using this version: `unix.IoctlGetWinsize(syscall.Stdout, unix.TIOCGWINSZ)`

Answer (score 28):

You can use `golang.org/x/term` package (https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/term)

Example

```golang
package main

import "golang.org/x/term"

func main() {
    if term.IsTerminal(0) {
        println("in a term")
    } else {
        println("not in a term")
    }
    width, height, err := term.GetSize(0)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    println("width:", width, "height:", height)
}
```

Output

```
in a term
width: 228 height: 27
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the unit of this result? `cm` or `px` or something else?

Comment: @JsonBruce rows and columns.

Comment: This is the best answer, as `golang.org/x/term` is up-to-date and a very simple package to use.

Comment: Some of the other answers are quite dated by now. A few of them recommends deprecated functions. So I think this answer should be accepted as the latest up-to-date one instead!

Answer (score 9):

Since no one else here has yet to present a cross-platform solution that will work on both **Windows** and **Unix**, I went ahead and put together a library that supports both.

https://github.com/nathan-fiscaletti/consolesize-go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/nathan-fiscaletti/consolesize-go"
)

func main() {
    cols, rows := consolesize.GetConsoleSize()
    fmt.Printf("Rows: %v, Cols: %v\n", rows, cols)
}
```

Comment: I wanted to confirm that it actually works on Windows. I have tried different scenarios, including exotic ones, like open vim and split window to get different sized terminal (inside another terminal, that runs vim). It works. I did get incorrect sized several times, but not ready to report that, since I'm not sure was it library fault or my sloppy testing.

Comment: @shytikov if the solution works for you, consider up-voting the answer :)

Comment: Yes, absolutely!

Answer (score 5):

If anyone's interested I made a package to make this easier.

https://github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    terminal "github.com/wayneashleyberry/terminal-dimensions"
)

func main() {
    x, _ := terminal.Width()
    y, _ := terminal.Height()
    fmt.Printf("Terminal is %d wide and %d high", x, y)
}
```

Comment: No windows support, this renders the package useless for cross-platform development.

Comment: @shytikov take a look at my answer here which does have windows support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63401154/1720829

Answer (score 0):

I have one implementation that uses `tcell` module, under the hood it will still use approach that based on calling native `dlls`, but if you're searching for terminal dimensions there is a great chance that you would need that package anyway:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gdamore/tcell"
)

func main() {
    screen, _ := tcell.NewScreen()
    screen.Init()
    
    w, h := screen.Size()
    fmt.Println(w, h)
}
```

Comment: In my use case I only needed the size and this made the normal `fmt.PrintX` behave oddly

Comment: If by "dlls" you mean DLLs -- dynamic link libraries -- that string isn't source code and shouldn't be highlighted as such. See [Highlighting technical words?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155904/highlighting-technical-words) and [Is it a good practice to add code brackets to technical terms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164309/is-it-a-good-practice-to-add-code-brackets-to-technical-terms) on [meta].

Comment: tcell is a fully fledged TUI library. I suggest something simpler, if this is the only usecase.