# how many terminal lines does a long line of text take?

Tags: tty

I am writing a program that acts as `tail -f`, but retains only the last `X` lines of terminal.

It is straightforward enough, except to handle long lines. If all lines are short, the main loop looks like (pseudo code):

```
last := readLine(stdin)
if lines.count > X then lines.removeFirst()
lines.addLast(last)
clearPrintedLines(count=X)
printLines()
```

My problem is, if `last` is long, the count of lines becomes wrong and more than `X` lines get printed.

Also, I want to preserve the commands output before the program runs, so clearing the whole screen is not an option (it would be simpler that clearing the last `X` lines, but less useful).

Comment: If there were a trivial, generic way to do this, writing a shell prompt wouldn't require mocking it up with `\[` and `\]` sequences to indicate which characters are non-printing (so the shell can count characters _outside_ those sequences to have an idea of where it expects the cursor to be). Which is all to say -- you'll typically need to do the work yourself. Is there a narrow, specific problem that prevents you from doing that?

Comment: (...for example, if you want to know how to get the terminal width on operating system X while writing code in language Y, that's a thing we could help you with; but so far you haven't described exactly what the problem is that you're stuck on).

Comment: (mind, _some_ TTYs have control sequences that let you query cursor position, but it's not a universal feature, and since you haven't specified anything about your target OS/terminal/etc, we have no grounds on which to say whether that capability would be available to you).

Comment: (btw, most of the functionality you need exists in programs and libraries that already exist -- "programs" in this context including screen or tmux, "libraries" referring to the several existing TUI "windowing" libraries for various languages; not knowing _your_ target language, we don't know if any of them are relevant).

Comment: target language is go; target OSs are osx/linux.

Comment: If we ignore the tricky corner cases (which there are moderately-well-established ways to handle, like transforming potentially-nonprinting characters to sequences of 7-bit-clean printable characters), [Get terminal size in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569433/get-terminal-size-in-go) gets you the instructions you need to figure out how wide the terminal is; so if you transform everything to printable ASCII characters that are known to use only one column, then it's just a question of counting how many characters you've printed on a line.

Comment: That said, all these details -- target language, target OS, etc -- should be present in _the question itself_; content only described in comments isn't fair game to use when writing an answer. Please [edit] towards that end.